# Can't get two javascript functions to run at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make my first website, the function that I am looking to get is I 
have a dropdown box where every option changes the hash. When the hash changes 
I have a certain table and image display based on which hash. So far I can get 
it to work but only with my first option. Whenever I try to add more only one 
of them is functioning.

So far I've tried fitting all of my code into a single function but that seems very tedious and it would involve me writing a massive amount of

elem = document.getElementById("xxxxx");
   elem.style.display = "block";

for every one of my options

```
function locationmario() {
      if (window.location.hash === '#Mario') {
      elem = document.getElementById("damagetablemario");
      elem.style.display = "block";
      elem = document.getElementById("marioimage");
      elem.style.display = "block";   
              }  else {
                 elem.style.display = "none";
                 elem = document.getElementById("damagetablemario");
                 elem.style.display = "none";

   }
}

function locationdk() {
   if (window.location.hash === "#Donkey-Kong") {
   elem = document.getElementById("damagetabledk");
   elem.style.display = "block";
   elem = document.getElementById("dkimage");
   elem.style.display = "block";   
                     } else {
                     elem = document.getElementById("dkimage");
                     elem.style.display = "none";
                     elem = document.getElementById("damagetabledk");
                     elem.style.display = "none";
                        }
  }

window.onhashchange = locationmario;
window.onhashchange = locationdk;
```

I want to be able to see my corresponding table and image for each hash that I switch to.

Comment: use `.addEventListener` you are reassigning the function. you could also merge the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really want to change more of your code, but the below should work.

First the clear_ids, simply loops through IDs and hides those divs by default. After that its just a simple IF else statement.

```js
function locationchange() {

var clear_ids = ["marioimage","damagetablemario","damagetabledk","dkimage"];
for(z=0;z<=clear_ids.length-1;z++){
  elem = document.getElementById(clear_ids[z]);
  elem.style.display = "none";
}

if (window.location.hash === "#Donkey-Kong") {
    elem = document.getElementById("damagetabledk");
    elem.style.display = "block";
    elem = document.getElementById("dkimage");
    elem.style.display = "block";   
}
else  if (window.location.hash === '#Mario') {
      elem = document.getElementById("damagetablemario");
      elem.style.display = "block";
      elem = document.getElementById("marioimage");
      elem.style.display = "block";  
 }

}

window.onhashchange = locationchange;
```

Comment: When I try using this I don't have anything show on my page regardless of what hash I'm on.

Comment: It looks like there was a typo. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

`window.onhashchange` can only point to one function, so in the case above it will only point to locationdk.  I suggest you refactor you code so that you have two if statements checking the `window.location`.